# Incorrect Output of List Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

My List is a list of dictionaries and i want to add another dictionary to it. But the output displays the items in the list inside each dictionary entry as [array].

```
dict={ 
 "Computer": [{"file" : "MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line" :[23,56]},
             {"file" :"MyDirectory/B/text5.txt", "line" :[32,91]}]
}

word="Computer"
key='123'
src="MyDirectory/C/text9.txt"

dict[word]=dict[word].concat({"file" : src, "line" : [key]})
console.log(dict)
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJPb4.jpg)

How can I make the output look like this:

```
{ "Computer":
    [ { "file":"MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line":[23,56]},
      { "file":"MyDirectory/B/text5.txt", "line":[32,91]},
      { "file":"MyDirectory/C/text9.txt", "line":[123]}]}
```

Comment: what do you want the output to be? –

Comment: "Computer": [{"file" : "MyDirectory/A/text1.txt", "line" :[23,56]},
                      {"file" :"MyDirectory/B/text5.txt", "line" :[32,91]},
                     {"file" : "MyDirectory/C/text9.txt", "line" :[123]}]                    
}

instead of the list of integers after "line" : , it just displays [Array] right now

Answer (score 2):

console.log() will only display your items to a certain depth. If you just need a pretty output try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dict, null, 2));
```

Comment: this takes up too many lines. Any way to output in the exact way i've described in the question?

Comment: AFAIK no, the "pretty formatting" of JSON.stringify() is fairly limited to it's purpose. If that isn't sufficient, you propably need to write your own output function, which produces the output string.

Comment: @HamzaAhmad Replacing spaces/newlines will make it "compact", `console.log(JSON.stringify(dict, null, 2).replace(/[ \n]/g,''))`.   This still seems like an X/Y problem.  A debugger makes viewing variables much easier.